# Include optgroup name along with selected value in select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I am having a select2 box. On selecting a value, is it possible to include the optgroup name to the selected value like below?

[image]

**Expected Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Not sure if it will work on all cases, but it works for multi select. Posting the code as it may be useful for someone.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function formatState(state) {
        console.log(state);
        if (!state.id) {
            return state.text;
        }
        var parent = state.element.parentElement;
        var $state = parent.label + "->" + state.text;
        return $state;
    }

    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
        data: data,
        maximumSelectionLength: 1,
        templateSelection: formatState
    });
});
```